# Google Places API Place.TYPE_ADDRESS missing?

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

Using Google Places API for Android, I'd like to know how to create an `AutocompleteFilter` of type `address`.  Specifically I don't know what value(s) to use for the `placeTypes` parameter in the `AutocompleteFilter.create` method (see https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.html).

According to documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3), the supported types are:

- `geocode` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results, rather than business results. Generally, you use this request to disambiguate results where the location specified may be indeterminate.
- `address` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified address.
- `establishment` instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only business results.
- ...

For `geocode` and `establishment`, the type values are defined in the `Place` class, namely `Place.TYPE_GEOCODE` and `Place.TYPE_ESTABLISHMENT`.  But there is no `Place.TYPE_ADDRESS`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_requests it looks like geocode might be the string to use?

Comment: I'm using android API.  And AutocompleteFilter.create takes Integer.

Comment: Also according to documentation, `geocode`, `address`, `establishment` are different types.  What I need are those `address` type places only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (and many others) have also noticed this. Unfortunately, it looks like address is not supported. See here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/issues/6#issuecomment-114951775

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Also saw: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8034.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=address&key=API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks, Verma.  But I'm using the Android API rather than web service.  I have revised my question to clarify this.